# How to add UniqueConstraint in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

How does one add a UniqueConstraint which is Case Insensitive using SQLalchemy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In some databases, string columns are case-insensitive by default (MySQL, SQL Server), so you wouldn't need to do anything extra.

In others, you can create a functional index that enforces the case-insensitive unique constraint:

```
Index('myIndex', func.lower(mytable.c.myColumn), unique=True)
```

You can also specify a case-insensitive collation for the column if the database supports it. For instance SQLite has a 'NOCASE' collation:

```
myColumn = Column(String(255), collation='NOCASE', nullable=False)
```

See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html?highlight=collation#sqlalchemy.types.String.params.collation

You may also specify a user-defined type for your column if your database provides a suitable one. PostgreSQL has a citext data type which is case-insensitive. See https://github.com/mahmoudimus/sqlalchemy-citext

Finally you can customize the DDL to create the constraint for your specific database.

Answer (score 5):

To add upon @jspcal's answer, if the model is defined using a `class`, then one you would have to either instantiate it independently after declaring the `model` or use the `text` construct.

i.e.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expressions import func

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    username = Column('username', String(24), nullable=False)
    
Index('user_username_index', func.lower(User.username), unique=True)
```

using the text construct:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expressions import text

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('ix_user_name', text('LOWER(username)')), 
    )
    username = Column('username', String(24), nullable=False)
```

NB: **table_args** needs to be a tuple or dict, hence the need for that trailing comma inside the parenthesis.

That will create an index on `username` column of table `user` in lowercase form. Therefore, data stored in this column is unique and case insensitive.