# In SqlAlchemy, how can I create a UniqueConstraint with the date part of a DateTime column and another column?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, unique-constraint

Let's say I have a model like:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, ForeignKey, Text

class Foo(declarative_base):
    __tablename__ = "foos"
    my_dt = Column(DateTime...)
    my_other_value = Column(Integer...)
```

I'm trying to make a [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint) using SqlAlchemy notation that would only allow one `my_other_value` per day, which means, I'd like to extract the `Date` part of `my_dt` and Uniquely constraint it with `my_other_value`

I know (erm... I'm *fairly sure I know*, rather) how to do it in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_num_and_date 
ON foos(my_other_value, date_trunc('day',my_dt));
```

but just out of curisity/consitency, I'd like to reflect that using SqlAlchemy.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056605/how-to-add-uniqueconstraint-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_model'
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('name', 'deleted_at'),)
    name = Column(String(length=64), nullable=False)
    deleted_at = Column(DateTime(), nullable=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, what I'm trying to do is extracting the `Date` part of the `DateTime` column and use that in the constraint itself. It would be something like: `__table_args__ = (
    UniqueConstraint('name', function_that_i_am_looking_for_that_extracts_the_date_from_column('deleted_at')),)` 
Sorry if the question wasn't clear.