# Silencing SQLAlchemy warnings

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm switching a legacy project over to autogenerate alembic migrations and it has some indexes that sqlalchemy doesn't recognize. When I run `alembic revision --autogenerate migration_name` an empty migration is created (because I have resolved all other inconsistencies) but I get 8 warnings like:

```
/project/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py:3328: SAWarning: Skipped unsupported reflection of expression-based index idx_name
  "expression-based index %s" % idx_name
```

In postgres, I look up the index definition like:

```sql
mydb=# SELECT tablename, indexdef FROM pg_indexes WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND indexname = 'idx_name';
 tablename |                                   indexdef                                    
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 plan      | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ON public.plan USING btree (lower((name)::text))
(1 row)
```

After reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50073468) I tried adding the index after the model definition and to `__table_args__`.

```py
# add it after model definition
class Plan(db.Model):
    __table_name__ = 'plan'
    # ...

db.Index('this_does_nothing_in_autogenerate', func.lower(Plan.__table__.c.name), unique=True)
```

```py
# Add it to table_args
class Plan(Base, db.Model):
    __table_name__ = 'plan'
    __table_args__ = (
        db.Index('idx_this_also_does_nothing', text('LOWER(name)')),
    )
```

Both these changes add warnings (shown below), create an empty migration, and do not remove the original warning. I get that sqlalchemy+alembic can't handle these more complex indexes, but is there any way to silence the warnings?

```
# Warning for first method
/home/chriscauley/develop/kennel/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/util/messaging.py:69: UserWarning: autogenerate skipping functional index this_does_nothing_in_autogenerate; not supported by SQLAlchemy reflection
  warnings.warn(msg)

# warning for second __table_args__ method
/home/chriscauley/develop/kennel/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/util/messaging.py:69: UserWarning: autogenerate skipping functional index idx_this_also_does_nothing; not supported by SQLAlchemy reflection
  warnings.warn(msg)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are a few ways to silence warnings. If you know where the warnings are being emitted you can create a context manager to capture that emitting function. As shown in the std-lib's documentation

```py
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()
```

Otherwise the method that is **not recommended** is to add the following to your main script:

```py
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

A more appropriate way of ignoring warnings ([pointed out to me here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48649917/3407256)) is to first check the warning options flag, this allows you to turn warnings back on by running your code with the `-W` flag (e.g. `python -W`):

```py
import sys
import warnings

if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

And finally to answer your question. The `warnings.filterwarnings` method has a `module` parameter which can allow you to specify a module you wish to suppress the warnings of. In your case it might be:

```py
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module="alembic.util.messaging")
```